# bash how to link multilines to command?

Tags: bash

I would like to do something like that inside the script

```
readonly refScript="./libs/refScript.sh"
readonly config=$(cat myConfig.txt) #multiline config file

readonly exec="$refScript $config"

$($exec "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4") #exec has problem because $config is multiline
```

I would like to do something like `$($exec "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4")` instead of and doing `$("$refScript" "$config" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4")`. How to do this?

Comment: Typical StackOverflow. 3 clowns that have English comprehension problems vote to close and it becomes closed without any review.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, already the cocept of

```
$($exec ....)
```

looks weird. It means that you first run the command stored in the variable `exec`, and then interpret the standard output of this command as another command to be executed. While this is not forbidden, I would be really surprised if you really intended it in this way.

But to focus on your original question: For passing the newline characters of your parameter configuration, just quote the evaluation:

```
./libs/refScript.sh "$(<myConfig.txt)" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"
```

Answer (score 1):

As usuall, use bash arrays.

```
refScript="./libs/refScript.sh"
config=$(<myConfig.txt)
exec=("$refScript" "$config")
"${exec[@]}" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"
```